# How do I remove a Google account from being an internal tester for my app?

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I have removed the email from the list of internal testers in Google Play Console. But when that Google account navigates to the Play Store on their device, it still shows the red text saying "You are an internal tester...".

When the user clicks on the invite link initially sent to enroll their account into the test, it simply says "Your account hasn't been invited to participate in this app's internal testing program".

So which one is it? The invite link is saying the account does not have access, and the Play Store is saying the account IS enrolled in the internal test! :s

Why is there no where that I can flick a switch that simply removes any specific user from the internal test?